# How to display the items from an array in PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have an associative array, I need to display the items in Excel sheet. May I know how I can do the **for loop** in **PHPSpreadsheet** ?

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
->fromArray(
    $arrayData,  // The data to set
    NULL,        // Array values with this value will not be set
    'A2',        // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
    'A1'         //    we want to set these values (default is A1)
);
```

Actually the above code is working fine. But I need to give some styles or colors to some item. As I display like above I don't know which section I need to change the style. If it is in **for loop** then it would be better.

Comment: Please advise what you have tried so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write data from array to sheet using phpspreadsheet library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681839/write-data-from-array-to-sheet-using-phpspreadsheet-library)

Comment: If you know the starting coordinates, then you can calculate which cell you need to modify.

Comment: But you know every time the array length will be different. That's why I'm looking for for loop

Comment: Yes, but you know the length of the array, so you can loop through the correct number of rows, right?